# Sending html code through json from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am getting following error in JS:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

How can I properly send HTML code (it's a whole page) through the JSON. 
I did not made this idea, but this is the plugin that I am trying to install, and I am getting this error. So if anybody can point me out what is wrong in here and how to fix it, it would be great. Thanks.
[image]

```
    public function ajaxfilter()
{
    $this->registry->set('bf_force_tmp_table_creation', true);
    $data = $this->_prepareFilterInitialData();

    $json = array();
    $route = $this->_getRequestParam('curRoute');
    if ($route && $this->_getRequestParam('withContent')) {
        $this->request->get['route'] = $route;
        $this->load->controller($route, $data);
        $json['products'] = $this->response->getOutput();
    }

    $this->load->model('module/brainyfilter');
    $model = new ModelModuleBrainyFilter($this->registry);

    $model->setData($data);

    if ((bool)$this->_getRequestParam('count', false)) {
        $json['brainyfilter'] = $model->calculateTotals();
    }
    if ((bool)$this->_getRequestParam('price', false)) {
        $minMax = $model->getMinMaxCategoryPrice();
        $min = floor($this->currency->format($minMax['min'], $this->_currency, '', false));
        $max = ceil($this->currency->format($minMax['max'], $this->_currency, '', false));
        $json['min'] = $min;
        $json['max'] = $max;
    }
    $this->log->debug($json);
    $isMijoShop = class_exists('MijoShop') && defined('JPATH_MIJOSHOP_OC');
    if ($isMijoShop) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        die(json_encode($json));
    } else {
        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, please show us your code which is causing this error. Secondly, why would you send HTML through JSON? The whole *point* of JSON is to send a data structure to be interpreted by the client. Either send the entire HTML response (which isn't a great idea) or use JSON as it was intended.

Comment: Encode your html string before sending.

Comment: I said this is not my idea, this is the plugin already made like that, I am trying to figure out why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to get a valid JSON string.

You can encode any scalar value, arrays and `stdClass` instances. For any other class, you may implement the [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface.

A simple HTML example:

```
<?php
$html = '<div class="container">What-Ever-Content </div>";
echo json_encode($html);
```

This will produce this output:

```
"<div class=\"container\">What-Ever-Content </div>"
```